# In Python 2.7. I am getting an error that I cannot resolve: TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)"

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite, wxpython

Trying to create a GUI which will move files from one directory to another.  If the files have been created/modified over 24 hours from the time it will list in a text box when the files were created/modified.

```
import os
import wx, DB_FILE
import shutil
import time

wildcard = "All files (*.txt)|*.*"

class File_Transfer(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'File Transfer', size=(420, 200))
        #Add dta to the list control
        self.fillListCtrl()
        panel = wx.Panel(self,-1)
        self.Directory = os.getcwd()

        panel.SetBackgroundColour("White")
        openButton = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Pull Files From:", pos=(10,0))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onOpenFile, openButton)
        placeButton = wx.Button(panel, -1, "New File Transfer to:", pos=(127,0))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.placeFile, placeButton)
        trsnfrButton = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Transfer File(s)", pos=(280,0))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.trnsfrFile, trsnfrButton)

        #SETUP THE TABLE UI
        #SETUP TABLE AS listCtrl
        self.listCtrl = wx.ListCtrl(panel, size = (100, 100), pos=(100, 40), style=wx.LC.REPORT |wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
        #Add columns to listCtrl
        self.listCtrl.InsertColumn(0, "ID")
        self.listCtrl.InsertColumn(1, "File_DESCRIPTION")
        self.listCtrl.InsertColumn(1, "Age")

    #Get dta from the database
    def fillListCtrl(self):
        self.allData = DB_FILE.viewAll()
        #Delete old data before adding new data
        self.listCtrl.DeleteAllItems()
        for row in AllData:
            #Loop through and append data
            self.listCtrl.Append(row)

    def addAge(self, event):
        name = dst
        age = mtime
        #Adding character to database
        DB_FILE.newfILE(name)
        DB_FILE.newfILE(age)
        print DB_FILE.viewAll()
        #Update list control
        self.fillListCtrl()

    def onOpenFile(self,event):

        dlg = wx.FileDialog(
            self, message="Select FILE",
            defaultDir=self.Directory,
            defaultFile="",
            wildcard=wildcard,
            style=wx.OPEN | wx.MULTIPLE | wx.CHANGE_DIR
            )
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            paths=dlg.GetPaths()
            print "You chose the following file(s):"
            for path in paths:
                 print path
                 global filePath
                 filePath=path
        dlg.Destroy()

    def placeFile(self, event):
        #Get directory where the files will go.

        dlg = wx.DirDialog(self, "Choose a directory:")

        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            paths = dlg.GetPath()
            print "You chose %s" % dlg.GetPath()
            for path in paths:
                global savePath
                savePath=dlg.GetPath()
                fileage_program.deleteCharacter(self.selectedId)
                #Refresh the table
                self.fillListCtrl()
        dlg.Destroy()

    #Transfer files from initial location to final location then states time
    def trnsfrFile(src,dst):
        src = filePath  #Original File address
        dst = savePath  #Move to directory

        #print file  # testing
        st=os.stat(src)
        ctime=st.st_ctime   #Current time
        global mtime
        mtime=(time.time() - ctime)/3600 #Subtract current time from last time file was touched and convert it to hours
        if mtime<24:                     #If time from creation is less than 24 hours then move files.
            shutil.move(src, dst)
            newFile()
            print dst

        else:
            print "file are: '%d' hours, since creation/modification" %mtime

#Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = File_Transfer()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Here is my database I am connected to:

```
import sqlite3

# Connect to simpsons database
conn = sqlite3.connect('FILE_INFO.db')

def createTable():
    conn.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists \
        FILE_INFO( \
        ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, \
        FILE_DESCRIPTION TEXT, \
        TIME INT);")

def newfILE(name,age):
    # Create values part of sql command
    val_str = "'{}', {}".format(\
        name, age)

    sql_str = "INSERT INTO FILE_INFO \
        (FILE_DESCRIPTION, TIME) \
        VALUES ('{}',{});".format(val_str)
    print sql_str

    conn.execute(sql_str)
    conn.commit()
    return conn.total_changes

def viewAll():
    # Create sql string
    sql_str = "SELECT * from FILE_INFO"
    cursor = conn.execute(sql_str)

    # Get data from cursor in array
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    return rows


createTable()
```

Comment: Where is the `rows` module coming from?

Comment: you don't need `import rows as rows`

Comment: I am learning Python and develop this code. When I try to use the rows variable I get global error.  Just trying to import database data into a text box.

Answer (score 0):

1-You don't really need to `import rows as rows` (if you `import rows` you will automatically be able to call the module as rows).

2-where is this .py file (rows.py) saved? Can you access the directory where it is from the directory where you are?

Just posting this answer to summarize the comments.

##############################################################################################revising my answer today, decided to edit

#

3-This error `TypeError:__init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)` usually happens when you miss in the argumentation. An argument, just to remember, is the word you put between `()` when you're making or calling a funtion. For example: `__init__(self)`: in this case `self` is an argument for the `__init__()` function. On your case, you're calling 3 of those `self, parent, id`. When you call this function you will need to use this three arguments, and it could be variables determined in another function or class, that you would need to determine as global for the program identifi it as the same variable usd above, or you can just substitute it for values of data (exp.: int, float, str), like: `__init__(self, 1, 42)`. The important thing is: you need to use the complete argumentation if it is the same function: if it has three args on it's definition, you need to call it with three args.